# Localized error messages with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

**Scenario 1:** Imagine you have a complex check or calculation in your business layer and the calcuation fails because some data are wrong or missing. You catch a computation exception for instance.

**Sceneraio 2:** Imagine you query your data layer (database) in your business layer and you catch a missing record exception.

**The task:** You are now in the business layer, hanging in the catch block with a yet unresolved exception. You would like to notify the user that there has been an error because parameter X did not match parameter Y and you need to localise the error message (for simplicity you have two languages).

**The questions:**

- a) How would you propagate the error to the presentation layer.
- b) How would you localise the error and keep the parameters in the message? e.g.: "Dear user the computation has failed because data X does not match data Y"

**The proposed answers:**

- a) You throw another exception from business layer having the previous as an inner exception.
- b) **This is the key answer I am looking for.** Let's assume you can afford giving away the parameter values because it is a intranet application and the user needs to know that those parameters are wrong.

The question is about application design - how to "translate/localise exceptions" or showing the user a translated/localised error message when you have a point in the code where the exception is caught and there can be multiple exceptions with multiple messages.

The exception messages are in a unified language, assume English.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean with your proposed answers, but @private_meta's answer looks pretty useful and straightforward for your case.

Comment: The question is about conception, design if you will, not about how to insert parameters into a string - "everybody" knows that.

Comment: I would like to know where else to ask such a question if you think it is too borad. I have not found any good article about it and I think this is a very common situation in which a lot of programmers get and struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this in our application.  The approach we take is:

1. **Catch no errors in the service layer.**  All exceptions are allowed to propagate back to the presentation layer method that made the original call.
2. **Throw custom exceptions in the data access layer.** Usually, when a data access exception occurs when you query your database, a database specific error is thrown.  Catch that exception in the data access layer but wrap it in a custom exception.  We have one called `DataAccessException` which has an enumerated property that indicates which data access layer call was made that caused the error and another that indicates if the cause of the error was access related (insufficient privilege) or because the database threw an error.
3. **Catch all errors in the presentation layer.**  In the presentation layer method that called the service layer, there is a `try-catch` block.  There is usually one `catch` clause for each exception type that you expect to be thrown by the code in the lower layers.  In that `catch` block, you create your localized message, log it to your event log, if any, and display the error to the user.
4. **All localizable strings should be resource strings.**  This isn't a hard and fast rule, but using the resource string approach means its easy to add support for other languages Windows supports in the future.  You define a resource identifier for each string that doesn't change.  The number of parameters each string takes doesn't change, either.  All that changes is the wording and where the "{0}", "{1}", etc. parameters appear in the string.

**Edit**

I'm responding to your comment here because the response is longer than I can fit in one comment.

The localized message is created based on the exception I'm handling in the particular `catch` block. I try to make the error message human readable.  That is, you have to assume that the reader is completely ignorant of any programming knowledge.  You describe what went wrong in general terms; its best not to mention the exact exception.  For example, the message for a `FileNotFoundException` when you try to open a file should say something like, "The file named "{0}" could not be found.  Please make sure you entered the file name correctly."  If there's someone in your family who isn't a programmer, just think about how you'd explain the problem to them & you'll probably have a good message.

As for what resource key to give it, I use a naming convention.  For our MVC web app, the convention is <Controller>*<Action>*<Message Name>.  Once the key is defined, the code always uses the key to retrieve the message by requesting the property with the same name as the key from the `ResourceManager` that VS builds.

The `ResourceManager` class that's created by VS as you build the resource strings uses the region settings to determine which local language message string to retrieve.  The returned string, plus whatever parameters are required, are passed to `string.Format` and the result is displayed or logged.

We have a rule in our code that the arguments to the message strings are always things that don't need to be translated to another language.  That is, either user inputted strings, or numbers or dates are OK, but enumeration values are not.  That's because our web app displays audit messages that are generated from itself and from a Windows WPF application and doesn't know about any of the enumerations in the WPF app.  Since the `ResourceManager` is a `partial` class, you could easily add methods to it that would localize your enumerations if you wanted to.  That's in your control.  You could then call that method to localize the enumerated value and then pass that to `string.Format` where you needed to do it.

Comment: How do you create the localised message? Is it based on the type of the exception or the exception carries some additional data (like resource string)?

Comment: Thanks for the exhausting comment/edit. This is exactly what I was eager to know - how the others handle the situation. The question maybe to broad to ask but I have not found any good article about it.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way I would go about doing this would be to localize a format string. Your Resources include the format string, like this:

```
string errorString "Dear user the computation has failed because data {0} does not match data {1}";
```

When throwing this exception or displaying the error, you just insert the data

```
string.Format(errorString, dataX, dataY);
```

**Edit:** As you want your exception text in a unified language and you don't want to map an exception type to a resource string later, the best option would be to supply the resource string to your exception as well as the data, or to have your exception carry the original message AND the translated message at the same time.

Another option for the mapping issue would be that you can use reflection. That way, you can just use your exception type and look up said type in the resources without explicitly mapping them. You would go to your Resources and look up a property called, for example, "Error_MyCustomException". That would give you one custom message per Exception type and all you have to store is the data.

Comment: The question is not about how to insert parameters into a string. The question is about how to "translate the exception", how to move the information (exception) from business layer into presentation layer and then translating it. You have multiple exceptions with multiple messages.

Comment: That depends where you want your translation/localization to happen. Do you want your exception to have translated message already? just put the resource string in the exception itself. Do you want to just display a translated message, get the resource string only when actually displaying it. if that's not the issue, I don't really get what's your problem.

Comment: The exception is in a unified language. The problem is where to store or how to retrieve the resource string, but I guess the only way is to customize the exceptions so they carry the resource strings with them. The question is basically about design - how would you throw and catch exceptions and show the user localised error messages. Translating the exception messages should be in my opinion done before showing them to the user, no sooner. I am protagonist of "English in code only".

Comment: As far as I see it you have two options. One would be to map your exception type to a resource string, another one would be to supply your Exception with the resource string in the beginning, maybe in addition to the default english message. If you don't want to actually translate the exception when you create it, your exception will have to carry the data you need.

Comment: It seems so. I started to have the idea when writing the last comment. Thank you for helping me to sort out my thoughts. Mapping the exception type to a resource seems rather harsh. You would have to have one exception for every case which might be quite excesive. I think I would go with the other solution.

Comment: Could you write that in your answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @Santhos added, with one additional option.